# Solve the stochastic differential equation

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, stochastic-integrals

I have to solve the following SDE:

$$dX_t=X_t dt+2W_tdW_t$$

---

Let $Y_t=X_t e^{-t}$. By Ito formula we have:

$$dY_t=-X_te^{-t}dt+e^{-t}(X_t dt+2W_tdW_t)=2e^{-t}W_tdW_t$$

Thus

$$Y_t=Y_0+2\int_0^te^{-s}W_sdW_s$$

Going back to $X_t$

$$X_t=e^{t}Y_0+2\int_0^te^{t-s}W_sdW_s$$

Is this correct?

Comment: Yes, it is correct.